# How do I access an out-of-scope variable from a callback in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following (contrived) code:

```
dbconn # this var holds the database connection
get_from_cache("missing_key")

defp get_from_cache(key) do
  Cachex.get(:my_cache, key, fallback: &from_db/1)
end

defp from_db(key) do
  select_from_db(dbconn)
end
```

The CacheX package says I can add a fallback function, which will be called if the key is not found in the cache. But that function needs more than just the key. I know I must be missing something here, but how do I access the dbconn variable from the callback in Elixir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a reference to a named function, you can pass an anonymous function to `Cachex.get` which can access variables declared outside the function:

```
# dbconn holds the database connection
Cachex.get(:my_cache, "missing_key", fallback: fn _key ->
  select_from_db(dbconn)
end)
```

Comment: What if the dbconn variable is not 'near', scope-wise, but in a function somewhere up the call stack. Would there be no other option than to pass it down all the way?

Comment: Can you post some example code? Variables are lexically scoped and anonymous functions can access variables defined more than one level up: `x = 1; (fn -> fn -> fn -> x end end end).().().() #=> 1`.

Comment: I modified the question a bit

Comment: That code doesn't make much sense. `dbconn` can't be outside a `def` because the code outside `def` is run at compile time. If you meant to put those two lines in another `def`, then the answer is that you can't access `dbconn` from another function. If there's only one instance of `dbconn` that's supposed to exist, you can store the conn in a named `Agent` and then access it using `Agent.get`.

Comment: That was indeed my intention. I'm going to study the Agent thingy. Thanks for your answer